# Error :- Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "

Tags: docker

I am asking for a massive favor. I was stuck below the issue for the last couple of days. If someone helps then that would be great. Going back to the issue. I have installed a docker and docker container using the following code (Docker-Apache spark).

```
    Docker File:-
    FROM debian:stretch
    MAINTAINER Getty Images "https://github.com/gettyimages"

    RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y locales \
     && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive locales \
     && locale-gen C.UTF-8 \
     && /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8 \
     && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
     && locale-gen \
     && apt-get clean \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    # Users with other locales should set this in their derivative image
    ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
    ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
    ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

    RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y curl unzip \
        python3 python3-setuptools \
     && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python \
     && easy_install3 pip py4j \
     && apt-get clean \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    # http://blog.stuart.axelbrooke.com/python-3-on-spark-return-of-the-pythonhashseed
    ENV PYTHONHASHSEED 0
    ENV PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8
    ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1

    # JAVA
    RUN apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre \
     && apt-get clean \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

    # HADOOP
    ENV HADOOP_VERSION 3.0.0
    ENV HADOOP_HOME /usr/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION
    ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
    ENV PATH $PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
    RUN curl -sL --retry 3 \
      "http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION.tar.gz" \
      | gunzip \
      | tar -x -C /usr/ \
     && rm -rf $HADOOP_HOME/share/doc \
     && chown -R root:root $HADOOP_HOME

    # SPARK
    ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.4.1
    ENV SPARK_PACKAGE spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-without-hadoop
    ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}
    ENV SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
    ENV PATH $PATH:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
    RUN curl -sL --retry 3 \
      "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/${SPARK_PACKAGE}.tgz" \
      | gunzip \
      | tar x -C /usr/ \
     && mv /usr/$SPARK_PACKAGE $SPARK_HOME \
     && chown -R root:root $SPARK_HOME

    WORKDIR $SPARK_HOME
    CMD ["bin/spark-class", "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"]
```

Command:

```
ubuntu@ip-123.43.11.136:~$ sudo docker run -it --rm  -v $(pwd):/home/ubuntu sparkimage /home/ubuntu bin/spark-submit ./count.py
```

Got Error below

```
Error :-  Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/home/ubuntu\": permission denied": unknown.
```

Can some help me what could be the issue? I have gone through several links but no luck still not able to resolve the issue.

```
ERRO[0001] error waiting for the container: context cancelled
```

Comment: Everything after the image name is interpreted as the command; it's as though you started the container and then ran `/home/ubuntu bin/spark-submit ./count.py`, which fails because `/home/ubuntu` is a directory and not a command.  Is the `/home/ubuntu` at the beginning just a typo; did you mean it to go somewhere else?

Comment: could you please provide the exact syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Everything passes after image `sparkimage` are considered as an argument to the Docker `Entrypoint`.

For example

```
Entrypoint ["node"]
```

so when you start

```
docker run -it my_image app.js
```

Now here `app.js` will be the argument for the `node` which will start `app.js` and docker will treat them like `node app.js`.

So you are passing invalid option to the image in your `docker run` command as there is no entrypoint in your Dockefile and command become

```
CMD ["/home/ubuntu bin/spark-submit ./count.py"]
```

That's is its throw error for `/home/ubuntu` permission denied.

You can try these two combinations.

```
Etnrypoint ["bin/spark-class", "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"]
```

with the run command.

```
sudo docker run -it --rm  -v $(pwd):/home/ubuntu sparkimage /home/ubuntu bin/spark-submit ./count.py
```

**OR**

```
CMD ["bin/spark-class", "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master","/home/ubuntu bin/spark-submit ./count.py"]
```

with docker run command

```
sudo docker run -it --rm  -v $(pwd):/home/ubuntu sparkimage
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. the corrected right mount path and executed and it was working fine without any issue.